# I need help with making realistic feathers

Tags: objects, particles, image, hair, photorealism

Right now I am making a Velociraptor head and I am having trouble with the feathers. I found a large amount of information on how to make the flight feathers for wings, but I am just making the head of the animal and need to make the head look like it is covered in body feathers and not long, stiffened wing feathers. I have been trying to use the particle tool to make it look more downy, but It keeps coming out looking like a bunch of single hairs instead of branching feathers. I was just wondering if someone could give me advice on how to make head and neck feathers to cover my Velociraptor with. I should also add that I am trying to make this look as realistic as I possibly can.

Comment: Hi , can you use texture instead ?

Comment: Hi. This question was put on hold because as it stands it is not answerable for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Remember only you have access to your scene, so unless you illustrate it thoroughly only you know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Please add [some accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above showing your setup. Don't post a comment or ask a new question, editing will automatically put it up for review so it can be reopened.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your work and reference images or a sketch of how you imagine a Velociraptor because nobody knows how they looked like when they lived. There are pictures of them with feathers and without, green-colored, brown-colored, etc. Maybe helpful: Grooming a parrot (https://youtu.be/8yoIW4va-VY). In the video hair cards for the feathers are created and used with a particle system + another particle system with clumped hair to mimic the feathers on the head.

Comment: Hey! I found this on twitter and tought it might be helpful!
https://twitter.com/JoannaKobierska/status/1440832423000895493?s=20